# How to break out from loop when a DOM element appears?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, puppeteer

I want to click through a gallery. Since I don't know how many pictures in the gallery are, I think I need a while loop. When I got to the last image, the next picture's button's classname changes to `next-photo is-hidden` until then it's simply `next-photo`.
So my goal is to have a while loop and when this button becomes hidden, break out from the loop, until then it should be called repeatedly.
Here I stand now:

```
async function openGallery(page) {
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    let randomTime = 250;
    let clickOnImage = document.querySelector('div.image');
    let nextbutton = document.querySelector('button[class="next-photo"]');
    let closeGallery = document.querySelector('button[class="close-gallery"]');
    let lastImage = document.querySelector('button[class="next-photo is-hidden"]');
    if (clickOnImage) {
      clickOnImage.click();
    }
    while (nextbutton) {
      nextbutton.click();
      if (lastImage) {
        closeGallery.click();
        break;
      }
      await delay(randomTime);
    }
  });
}
```

But now, when I reach the last picture, the program won't break out of loop, or in other words, other codes after this one won't execute. And the gallery won't close.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `lastImage` once at the beginning before the `is-hidden` class is added. Once the `is-hidden` class is added later it doesn't matter because `lastImage` is already set.

You could do `lastImage = document.querySelector('button[class="next-photo is-hidden"]');` again each time right before `if (lastImage) {`.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is probably that you're only searching for `lastImage` before all the clicking has been done, which means it doesn't exist yet. A fix would be to move that line to within the while loop, but in general the code you've given all looks a bit verbose. I'd probably use some kind of recursive function instead, similar to the below:

```js
function updateContent() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      var button = document.getElementById('button');
      button.innerHTML = parseInt(button.innerHTML) + 1
      if (button.innerHTML === '5') {
          button.className = "unclickable"
          button.disabled = true
      } else {
          button.click()
      }
  }, 500)
}
```

```html
<button id="button" class="clickable" onclick="updateContent()">1</button>
```